# How to discovery available network printers from Ubuntu CLI

Tags: networking, printing, cups-lpd

I've been looking for a way to discovery existing network printers from Ubuntu command line with standard tools. The IP addresses of printers are unknown.

So far I've managed to do this with `nmap -p T:9100 192.168.0.0/24`. This works, but I feel it a bit overkill procedure. I suppose there is some kind of standard way to discovery printers instead of scanning the ports, or is there?

Comment: Maybe try: `nmap -p T:631 192.168.0.0/24 | grep -B4 open` Port 631 is used by CUPS in Linux.

Comment: My Canon Pixma 2960 had port 515 open FWIW.